# React Redux 'npm run deploy' app not working

Tags: deployment, reactjs, redux

I'm having some issues when trying to deploy a simple react + redux app.

I'm using the [react redux starter kit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit)

When running the app in development `npm run dev:nw` all is good, the `this.props.startTimer()` function in `componentWillMount()` fires and updates the state in intervals in the module. Everything just works.

When i deploy the app with `npm run deploy` i get no errors and all seems to work without problems.

```
app:config Create configuration. +0ms
app:config Apply environment overrides for NODE_ENV "production". +3ms
app:webpack:config Create configuration. +839ms
app:webpack:config Enable plugins for production (OccurenceOrder, Dedupe & UglifyJS). +2ms
app:webpack:config Apply ExtractTextPlugin to CSS loaders. +69ms
app:bin:compile Run compiler +4ms
app:build:webpack-compiler Webpack compile completed. +14s
app:build:webpack-compiler Hash: ce8ff073e185128cb7b1
Version: webpack 1.12.9
Time: 13543ms
```

Alot of react/babel/redux built messages folllows. Finally the output ends with

```
app:build:webpack-compiler No errors or warnings encountered. +2ms
app:bin:compile Copy static assets to dist folder. +0ms
```

I navigate to **http://domain/dist** , page shows up looking just as in dev, but the this.props.startTimer() won't fire as it did just fine in development, nothing happens. The scripts are there and all looks just fine but nothing happens.

What could be causing this?

I've tried setting **NODE_ENV** to both base, development  & production.
No changes.

In need of help

Comment: is there a public repo to view? and maybe a pointer to the component causing problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a misconfigured nginx that didn't handle the dist/ folder properly. Moved the content to the document root and it worked.